# Is there a dunder attribute that gets me the filename of where the function is currently being used at?

Tags: python

I have a helper function in various files, let's call them `import_1.py` and `import_2.py` for the most part they're largely the same except for its usage of `__file__`.

`import_1.py`:

```
def print_whoami():
    print(f'hello my name is {__file__}')
```

`import_2.py`:

```
def print_whoami():
    print(f'hello my name is {__file__}')
```

These functions are called by let's call it `main.py`.

`main.py`:

```
import import_1
import import_2

import_1.print_whoami()
import_2.print_whoami()
```

But the issue is this is quite a lot of repeat code. Would it be possible to abstract `print_whoami` to an outside function but somehow be able to preserve `__file__` output?

i.e.

`utils.py`:

```
def print_whoami():
    print(f'hello my name is {__file__}')
```

`import_1.py`:

```
from utils import print_whoami()
```

`import_2.py`:

```
from utils import print_whoami()


import import_1
import import_2

import_1.print_whoami()
import_2.print_whoami()
```

The issue with this is that `__file__` will always reference `utils` now. Is there another dunder attribute that I could reference that gets me the filename where it's being imported from? i.e. `import_1.py` and `import_2.py`

Comment: Just make it a parameter of the function and pass `__file__` where you call it

Comment: See [**`inspect.getfile`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile).

Comment: @RunOrVeith that would always give you the `__file__` of the one actually calling the function. It won't give me what I need.

Comment: @PeterWood ah inspect.getfile(imported_2.print_whoami) will actually get what I need.